# create temp table with conditional criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a temporary table from another table, where I select rows based on a set of criteria. The many different criteria are in the "where"-statement. The rows are mainly selected based on criterias from two different columns ("Värde" and "Adminkontroll"). The first three conditions is that I dont want any rows with a certain text in the column Adminkontroll. The last three conditions is that, if the row has a certain text in the column Adminkontroll, I just want to select those with a certain value below, or above AND below a specific threshold level. My code looks likt this:

```
    select * into temp1 
    from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] E
    where
            E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_annan_AID'
        and E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_lararloner'
        and E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_specialitet'
        and E.Värde < 90 if E.Adminkontroll IN 'SKL_admin_KN_ldatum'
        and (E.Värde < 50 and E.Värde > 95) if E.Adminkontroll IN 'SKL_admin_KN_tillsvidare'
        and (E.Värde < 5 and E.Värde > 25)if E.Adminkontroll IN 'SKL_admin_KN_timlon'


    select * into temp1
```

Does anyone has any ideas on how to code it so that is works? I have tried with "cast (case..)" but dont know how to code it when I need this specific criterias.

Many thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Hannes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it´s correct even though I may have been fuzzy in my description, I want to select the values that is either below 50 or above 95. In the data, that corresponds to all the values that are supposed to be incorrect in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try..

```
select * into temp1 
from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] E
where
        ( E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_annan_AID'
    AND E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_lararloner'
    AND E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_specialitet'
    AND E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_ldatum'
    AND E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_tillsvidare'
    AND  E.Adminkontroll <> 'SKL_admin_KN_timlon'
        )
    OR ( E.Värde < 90 AND E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_ldatum')
    OR ( E.Värde < 50 and E.Värde > 95 AND E.Adminkontroll ='SKL_admin_KN_tillsvidare')
    OR (E.Värde < 5 and E.Värde > 25 AND  E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_timlon')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a cleaner way to organize your rules and avoid coding errors.

```
    select * into temp1 
    from [StatistikinlamningDataSKL].[dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] E
    where 1 = case
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_annan_AID'                                     then 0
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_lararloner'                                    then 0
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_specialitet'                                   then 0
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_ldatum'      AND E.Värde < 90                  then 1
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_tillsvidare' AND E.Värde < 50 AND E.Värde > 95 then 1
      when E.Adminkontroll = 'SKL_admin_KN_timlon'      AND E.Värde < 5  AND E.Värde > 25 then 1
      else 0
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I really like the structure. Somehow though, the code only returned a fraction of the correct number of rows. Have a nice weekend!